# pytorch tensor sort rows based on column

Tags: python, sorting, pytorch, tensor

In a 2D tensor like so

```
tensor([[0.8771, 0.0976, 0.8186],
        [0.7044, 0.4783, 0.0350],
        [0.4239, 0.8341, 0.3693],
        [0.5568, 0.9175, 0.0763],
        [0.0876, 0.1651, 0.2776]])
```

How do you sort the rows based off the values in a column? For instance if we were to sort based off the last column, I would expect the rows to be such...

```
tensor([[0.7044, 0.4783, 0.0350],
        [0.5568, 0.9175, 0.0763],
        [0.0876, 0.1651, 0.2776],
        [0.4239, 0.8341, 0.3693],
        [0.8771, 0.0976, 0.8186]])
```

Values in the last column are now in ascending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t = torch.rand(5, 3)
COL_INDEX_TO_SORT = 2

# sort() returns a tuple where first element is the sorted tensor 
# and the second is the indices of the sorted tensor.
# The [1] at the end is used to select the second element - the sorted indices.
sorted_indices = t[:, COL_INDEX_TO_SORT].sort()[1] 
t = t[sorted_indices]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = <your tensor>
ind = a[:,-1].argsort(dim=0)
a[ind]
```

`argsort` "Returns the indices that sort a tensor along a given dimension in ascending order by value." So, basically, you get sorting indices for the last column and reorder the rows according to these indices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sorted and lambda function such as below.  The sorting key is the last item in the list, x[-1]

```
tensor = [[0.8771, 0.0976, 0.8186],
        [0.7044, 0.4783, 0.0350],
        [0.4239, 0.8341, 0.3693],
        [0.5568, 0.9175, 0.0763],
        [0.0876, 0.1651, 0.2776]]
sorted(tensor,key=lambda x: x[-1])


Result: 

 [[0.7044, 0.4783, 0.035],
 [0.5568, 0.9175, 0.0763],
 [0.0876, 0.1651, 0.2776],
 [0.4239, 0.8341, 0.3693],
 [0.8771, 0.0976, 0.8186]]
```